# Browser support message pop up plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I know there are plugins like https://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/ and http://browser-update.org that are extremely handy to warn users to not use IE6/7.

But what if I would like to go a step further and customise the detection to say "Sorry, IE is not supported, Please download Chrome"? Are there such plugins out there? Thanks

Comment: I don't want to be "one of those people" but are you really doing anything so cutting edge and radical that IE6 or IE7 wouldn't at least function? People who're forced to use those browsers are used to a poor looking experience but your site should at least be functional.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not involved with the backend development, so I can't really say much about that. but one thing I can say is that we are hacking this prototype together as quickly as we can, which most likely would mean it's not done perfectly.

Comment: That's fair enough. Try not to incur too much debt going that rapidly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a great place to get the answers you're looking for, but sometimes the answer you're looking for is not the answer you *actually need*. In this case, I must give you the later, since giving you the former would be a great disservice to you and your peers.

Do not attempt to detect a single browser, and funnel your traffic into another browser - it will be bad for business, bad for your career, and bad for the entire web as a whole. I mean no disrespect, I merely speak as somebody who has been observing the web for over a decade.

The users who are on Internet Explorer 6 today are not there because it's their favorite browser, so asking them to change is only going to frustrate them, and potentially drive them away from your site. More on this, and related points in Kyle Simpson's talk [Browser Versions are Dead](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAxTilYa5bo). As the well-known developer Nicholas Zakas said, [It's time to stop blaming Internet Explorer](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/12/its-time-to-stop-blaming-internet-explorer/).

As far as Internet Explorer in general, the latest installments are incredible. Internet Explorer 9 marked a radical change in the product, showing an increasing support for web standards. Internet Explorer 10 was released quickly thereafter (shattering the idea of a 2-year release cycle), and shows support for many "CSS3" features that not even Chrome yet supported.

The industry itself seems to be appreciating Internet Explorer today, including tech-giants [Leo Laporte and Steve Gibson](https://soundcloud.com/jonathansampson/leo-laporte-and-steve-gibson). Lea Verou (creator of [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/), [Prism](http://prismjs.com/), and [W3C Staff Member](http://www.w3.org/People/#lea)) has publicly stated that "IE *was* a crappy browser several versions ago. IE10 is actually very good, not just decent". Also it was [announced](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/14/the-state-of-jquery-2013/) that "jQuery 2.0 now has more patches and shims for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox than for Internet Explorer!"

I've found time and time again lately that when Internet Explorer 10 is rendering something incorrectly, it is by and large typically caused by a developer attempting some "clever trick" to detect Internet Explorer and serve up alternative content. One recent example was from a site attempting to deliver content only to IE7 and up, doing the following:

```javascript
if ( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) < 7 ) {
    /* Assume this is IE6 or below, and deliver substandard experience */
}
```

This little trick suggested version "10.0" was actually Internet Explorer 1, and delivered a horrible experience. Fixing this code, resulting in IE getting the same experience designed for Chrome, resulted in a restored site - *everything just worked*. This isn't uncommon today, it [has happened](http://blog.reybango.com/2012/05/08/hey-paydirt-your-site-works-just-fine-in-ie/) over, and over again.

Rather than focusing on how you can get your visitors to install new software to view your website, focus instead on writing standards-based markup, using best-practices like progressive enhancement, feature-detection, polyfills when necessary, and be alright with your site gracefully degrading in older browsers. After all, your website doesn't need to [look the same](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/) in every browser out there.

Lastly, the cost of testing Internet Explorer today has nearly vanished. Although it's not available on Mac, and older versions of Windows, every single version of Internet Explorer (6 through 10, Modern and Desktop) is available for use via BrowserStack ([3 months free](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#browserstack), courtesy of Microsoft), as well as via free downloadable virtual machines over at [modern.IE](http://modern.ie). Not to mention the in-browser emulation, [which excited](https://twitter.com/chriscoyier/status/178508977578053633) Chris Coyier of CSS-Tricks.

With regards to the future of Internet Explorer, David Storey (recenty of Opera, and a W3C WG member) suggests [it's looking very bright](http://generatedcontent.org/post/47216611856/ie11).

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan-sampson. Great reply & very insightful indeed! I have to admit, I am perhaps guilty of being bias against IE. Being primarily a Mac user the only time I use IE is when I have CSS styling issues to fix. I do admit I rarely hear of issues with IE9 / IE10 so credits are definitely due there. As a startup, we are so keen to launch our new site ASAP to start validating, but so often I find we can't launch yet because X doesn't work on IE7/8. As you pointed out this could be due the way the backend is coded, but it is just so frustrating being held back this way. Huge Thanks!

Comment: @ChiWaiLi Regarding 7/8, your best bet is to take an approach similar to HTML5Boilerplate and use conditional comments to load the `<HTML>` tag with classes like `.lt-ie8 .lt-ie7` and use these in an extra stylesheet, also loaded using conditional comments. Your valid and standards-based markup should work fine in 9/10. Help is always around the corner; Microsoft recently launched the [@IEDevChat](https://twitter.com/IEDevChat) account on twitter, as well as formed the "#ieuseragents" hashtag, where a team of developers (of which I am one) offer free assistance online. Ping us anytime.

Comment: Again, learnt another thing I didn't know, Microsoft support via Twitter, that's pretty impressive. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend an alert but I put one together anyway, just because I understand what drives a developer to this kind of thing... IE sucks less? really?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/W9gPQ/18/)

Alert option

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script>alert("Sorry, IE is not supported, Please download Chrome");</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Less intrusive `<div>` option

```
    <!--[if IE]>
<div id="box">Sorry, IE is not supported, <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?hl=en&brand=CHMA&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-bk&utm_medium=ha">Please download Chrome</a></div>
<![endif]-->
```

You can use the `<!--[if IE]>` for any content you would like to display only when a user views your page in IE, works for css work-arounds also.

Comment: Yeah, an alert does seem to be a bit harsh, so I will give the less intrusive approach a go. Thank you for your help