# target ie and non-ie not work? my ie version's ie10

Tags: html, target, internet-explorer-10

here's my code. when using ie, i want it show "please change your browser!", and only the non-ie browsers can see other code. but it doesn't work in ie10 (ie 10 doesn't show h1 but the other code) what's wrong with my code?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sisu|Swap</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--[If IE]> 
<h1 style="color: white">please change your browser!</h1>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>--> 
  <header>
    <img src="imgs/header.jpg" />
  </header>

  <footer>

  </footer>

</body>
</html>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e)

Comment: If there's a reason to exclude IE10 due to missing features, you should probably exclude it using feature detection for the required missing feature rather than by name.

Comment: [Do not do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066175/browser-support-message-pop-up-plugin/16072651#16072651).

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer 10 doesn't support conditional comments, see the [MSDN page about conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> **Important**  As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode.  Use feature detection to provide [effective fallback strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273396(v=vs.85).aspx) for website features that aren't supported by the browser.  For more info about standards mode, see [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx).